Docker: Accessing a host folder from a container folder
I want to access some files kept on the host from the docker container.
Edit-
My use case:

I have a Spring Boot app (rest-service) that reads a file stored on the local(host) system. It's jar will run in the docker container.
I have an other docker containerized application (QE app) that uses the jar of the spring boot app.
So, I have 2 containerized applications - 1. spring boot app and 2. the QE app
I am required to hit a rest service from the QE which I am able to do.
But since, the service's jar (running in the container) doesn't have access to the host file, my service is not working properly.
That's why I want to access a folder kept on the host from the service running in the docker container.

What I've done:

executed the following command to copy the contents of the host folder to the container's folder
docker run -d --volume C:\host_folder:/conf/container/tmp d9746fe0b603 sleep infinity

Upon executing the followng command - docker exec -it cd8ca46e46c6 sh 
I am able to check that contents of the  C:\host_folder are copied to the /conf/container/tmp folder in the container. Attached Screenshots.
But when I am running the application in the container,
getting the same error - the service can't find the file stored on the host system. 


Attaching a few screenshots-



I tried restarting and rebuilding the container using - docker-compose up --build but that's not working. Can anybody tell me what's the issue and how I can fix that. TIA

Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  One of the key design goals of Docker is that containers can't normally access host files; would it make sense to run the program directly on the host, not in a container?

@DavidMaze Now, I have added my use case as an example. Please check the description.

Containers also can't normally access each others' files.  Can you run at least the first application directly on the host?  And then, when you invoke the second application, send the file content in something like the body of an HTTP POST request?  Seeing some of the actual code will probably be more useful in helping to understand the setup and problem than heavily redacted screen shots.

Problem with the approach that I have discussed under What I've done in the description: 

Able to successfully copy the files from host_folder to the container_folder.
But as soon as, I was building the containers again - docker-compose up --build, the updates were getting lost. (Because the commands were run on a console, may be!)

Solution that finally worked for the discussed case - 
In the docker-compose file, inside the image, under the volumes tag mention the folders that you want to mount, like given below:
application-mage:
  .
  .
  volumes:
    - C:/host_folder/:/conf/container_folder/tmp/

